# PostgreSQL Export to CSV. Each element of array in new line

Tags: postgresql

I have next request

```
\copy (
  SELECT users.name, ARRAY_AGG(emails.email), ARRAY_AGG(addresses.address)  
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN emails USING(id)
  LEFT JOIN addresses USING(id)
  GROUP BY users.email
) TO 'path/to/file.csv' WITH csv header;
```

and it exports data in next way

```
|John Doe|{email1@qq.qq,email2@qq.qq}|{addr1,addr2}|
```

is it possible to export array in multiline cell? To have next view

```
-----------------------------
|John Doe|aaaaa1@aa.aa|addr1|
|        |aaaaa2@aa.aa|addr2|
-----------------------------
|Foo Bar |bbbbb1@bb.bb|addr9|
|        |bbbbb2@bb.bb|addr8|
|        |bbbbb3@bb.bb|     |
-----------------------------
```

I've tried to join array into a string with `\r\n`, but it doesn't work

Is it possible at all?

Comment: *and it exports data in next way* I doubt. Output is grouped by name whereas in the query you group by email...

Comment: The desired output makes no sense to me as a CSV file. I highly doubt there will be tools that can deal with the implied "if no value is present in the first column use the previous available value" rule there. Unless you want to print that file, I would very much assume this will give you a lot of trouble if you want to process it with other tools. `psql` will certainly not be able to import that

Answer (score 1):

Test:

```
\copy (
  SELECT CASE WHEN users.name = LAG(users.name) OVER (ORDER BY users.name, 
                                                               users.email, 
                                                               addresses.address) 
              THEN '' 
              ELSE users.name
              END, 
         emails.email, 
         addresses.address
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN emails USING(id)
  LEFT JOIN addresses USING(id)
  ORDER BY users.name, 
           users.email, 
           addresses.address
) TO 'path/to/file.csv' WITH csv header;
```

Comment: I was going to suggest exactly this approach! Use LAG() to see if the previous row's name is the same: if so, output nothing instead.